# OpenCV: Ignore text-like contours

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

**Background**

I want to detect all contours in an image that contains 2D geometric shapes, but strip away anything that looks like text.

Example input:
[image]

I tried to detect text areas via Tesseract and remove those text areas subsequently. For some images where the OCR recognition is good this works fine, thus text areas are recognized with quite good rate and contours of recognized text can then be removed. But for most images the text is not recognized well and thus I cannot remove irrelevant text contours from the image.

Therefore my question is: How can I distinguish text-like contours from my 2D "geometric" contours?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the text and just want to get rid of it, then you can just detect outer contours by passing `RETR_EXTERNAL` as the mode parameter to the `findCountours()` function. That will give you the outermost contours and ignore anything contained inside of the geometric shapes.

Or if you want more control, you can pass the mode parameter as RETR_TREE and then walk the tree, keeping only the top-level contours and ignoring anything below that level in the hierarchy.  That way you'll get everything and you can decide later what you want to keep and what you want to ignore.

Read [this page](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html) of the OpenCV documentation for information on how `findCountours()` represents the hierarchy (that page is from a python tutorial, but it's generic enough to follow along).

Of course that will only work if the images always look similar to the example you gave in your question - i.e. the text is always inside of the geometric shapes.  If you have text outside of the shapes, then maybe you could look at the size of the contours (bounding rectangles) and ignore anything that falls below a certain threshhold (assuming text contours will be much smaller than your geometric shapes).

Comment: I realize I should have given a better example. Unfortunately this won't work, because I do not know the nesting level. I have for example neighboring rectangles which create an outer rectangle (which I need to optimize away also), and text can appear in any nesting depth. Edit: I also thought about comparing area size - but I hope for something more sophisticated since the etxt can also be of any size.

Comment: Maybe a combination of the two methods, then?  Use RETR_TREE and then look for a group of (two or more) small contours inside a larger contour where the difference in the area of the bounding rectangles is greater than x percent?  I dunno, just throwing out ideas.  I just think trying to recognize text with OCR is overkill since you don't care about the contents of the text and just want to filter out stuff that it isn't part of the shape.  Will the text always be a certain color, or a limited set of colors?  Maybe look for groups of black or white pixels surrounded by another color?

Comment: Or maybe apply a gaussian blur to the image first?  If you blur it enough, the text might get fuzzy enough that `findCountours()` won't find it, then it will only give you the geometric shapes?   Just another idea...

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll experiment a bit more, and try also with blurring.

Answer (score 1):

Contours that belong to text, also represent a region according to your example. So that you can try to use the properties of regions to eliminate some unneeded regions (text contours!) I can suggest that you can use some properties like **eccentricity**, **solidity** or **compactness** (you can find code example here:   [https://github.com/mribrahim/Blob-Detection](http://github.com/mribrahim/Blob-Detection) 
 )

For ex: Regular shapes and the others can be distinguished by using **compactness** value, or you can combine any other properties